# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (duplicate)

Tags: python

Ok I have looked at similar questions but it didn't seem to help mine, but everyone's code is different and I am also a beginner at Python coding. Can someone help me figure this out so I can know how to deal with this next time it pops up?

```
        def run(self):
               while True:
                      c, a = self.sock.accept()
                      cThread = threading.Thread(target=self.handler, args=(c,a))
                      cThread.daemon = True
                      cThread.start()
                      self.connections.append(c)
                      print(self.connections)
```

The error I get point to: def run(self):   exactly how it prints in the terminal.

edit: I have changed the screwed up part of the code as I didn't notice it till people pointed it out. Now it looks as it does in my laptop. But the problem still persists.

Comment: Show the code around this and the exact error with trace.

Comment: Is `args=(c,a$` correct? Seems like it should be `args=(c,a)`.

Comment: In line `cThread = threading.Thread(target=self.handler, args=(c,a$`, where are `)`s ?

Comment: You're either mixing tabs and spaces or just using arbitrary indentation

Comment: the line with args=(c,a$ is correct because when I formatted it to here it changed. on my laptop its actually  args-(c,a))

Comment: Convert all indent to space or tabs. Use any one of them not both.

Comment: Python needs 4 spaces for indentation. Probably you are using tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: As I said I am new so I am still learning about the spaces rule..now I got to go learn more on tabs

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional amount of indentation in your code. By default the indentation level is 2/4 in python. To get your code working, reduce the indentation level. There is also an error in your code, You missed a `)`. BTW, It is always better to include the error you have received in your question.

```py
def run(self):
    while True:
        c, a = self.sock.accept()
        cThread = threading.Thread(target=self.handler, args=(c,a)
        cThread.daemon = True
        cThread.start()
        self.connections.append(c)
        print(self.connections)
```

Comment: I have done all of that and it still is giving me the same error on that piece of code. This is semi frustrating lol